converting std::vector of gpumats to torch::Tensor
i have a vector of gpumats and i want to stack them and convert them to torch::Tensor. I used Yolo8 segmentation exported as torchscript for my model.
here is my code:
torch::Tensor TorchSegmentation::preprocess(std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> &src_imgs){

    int idx = 0;
    for (auto &img : src_imgs) {
        int originalWidth = img.cols;
        int originalHeight = img.rows;

        int right = originalWidth > originalHeight ? 0 : originalHeight - originalWidth;
        int bottom = originalHeight > originalWidth ? 0 : originalWidth - originalHeight;
        // Padding to make the image square
        cv::cuda::copyMakeBorder(img, img, 0, bottom, 0, right, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        // Resize the padded image to the target size
        // cv::cuda::resize(img, img, input_size);
        // if(idx == 0)
        cv::Mat t;
        img.download(t);
        imgs.push_back(t);
        cv::cuda::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

        img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC3, 1.0f / 255.0f); // normalization
        idx++;
    }

    auto rows = input_size.height;
    auto cols = input_size.width;
    int type = src_imgs[0].type();

    int bRows = 0;
    for (auto &gimg : src_imgs) {
        bRows += gimg.rows;
    }

    cv::cuda::GpuMat batch_image(bRows, cols, type);
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < src_imgs.size(); ++i) {
        auto gimg = src_imgs[i];
        gimg.copyTo(batch_image(cv::Rect(0, offset, cols, gimg.rows)));
        offset += gimg.rows;
    }

    auto batch_size = static_cast<int>(src_imgs.size());
    std::vector<int64_t> sizes = {batch_size, static_cast<int64_t>(batch_image.channels()),
                                  static_cast<int64_t>(src_imgs[0].rows),
                                  static_cast<int64_t>(src_imgs[0].cols)};

    long long step = batch_image.step / sizeof(float);

    std::vector<int64_t> strides = {1, 1, step, static_cast<int64_t>(batch_image.channels())};

    torch::Tensor input_tensor = torch::from_blob(batch_image.data, sizes, strides, torch::kCUDA).contiguous().to(device_type);
    return input_tensor;
}

should i change any parameters or variable for it to work correctly with batch size > 1. I think i should change something in strides vector.
i have tested my code with batch size 1 and it works correctly but for batch size > 1 i have problems with images with index more than 0 for example src_imgs[1]. by problem i mean the number of boxes that remain after nms are lower than when i use normal cv::Mat and the location of the boxes are incorrect too.
